# Rotation angle constraints in Unity3d?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

In unity3d, how can I set rotation angle constraints to a sphere along the x and y axis'? For example, if I want the sphere to only rotate up along the x axis 90 degrees, how can I prevent it from going any further than that? I am using a character controller to control my sphere. It can only rotate +/- a certain angle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access angles that are written in inspector like this:

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(x, y, z);
```

If you want rotation on one axis to be constant just make value of rotation literal.

Answer (score 1):

Before assigning your angles you'll just have to clamp them.

Use

```
angle = Mathf.Clamp(angle , min , max)
```

Then you can assign the angle to your transform.localEulerAngles